# Generate dropdown fields in gridview with options as values in columns with the same ID in another column

Tags: sql, .net, t-sql, gridview, dropdown

I''m having trouble generating dropdown fields in which **T_ID**s with similar **ID** are grouped and put inside the dropdowns as options- forming a list of dropdown fields inside a gridview. This is written in c# .net (webforms) with sql server.

I illustrated below the output I'm expecting. If someone could help me with this it'd be appreciated. Thanks!

db table:

```
 ID |   T_ID   | Name
----+----------+------
 1  |    98    | Joe
 1  |    34    | Joe
 1  |    56    | Joe
 1  |    12    | Joe
 2  |    67    | Mary
 2  |    12    | Mary
 3  |    87    | Penn
 3  |    23    | Penn
 3  |    61    | Penn
```

expected output:

```
(ID 1)
Joe | 98 | -dropdown 
    | 34 |
    | 56 |
    | 12 |
    | 22 |

(ID 2)
Mary| 67 |
    | 12 |

(ID 3)
Penn| 87|
    | 23|
    | 61|
```

or

[image: dropdowns]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. The expected output is a gridview where names are in one column, and the second column is a dropdown with all T_ID's related to the name? What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I apologize if my question is somewhat confusing, I'm having difficulty writing this in English. I want to generate dropdown fields which options are the values in the column T_ID grouped by ID which is the Name's ID. See the 'expected output' part of the question, those are my illustration of the dropdowns I'm hoping to generate.

Comment: Already seen the expected output, I'm asking if this is a label column and a dropdown column. Also, as it is now, your question is too broad. You should narrow the scope of your question to the particular part of the task that you can't solve on your own. You don't expect us to provide a fully functional sql + c# solution, right? One more thing - you should specify the UI framework you are working with - asp.net? wpf? winforms? some other UI framework?

Comment: I updated the question.. I have actually generated the output but I don't think the way I made it is ideal. It's too long and slow, since I have over 30k items in the table.

Comment: Depending on the grid's capabilities, this might be solved by selecting all records from the table, and just filtering the values in the dropdown when it's being opened. I'm not sure that's the best approach but it is possible.